# Can I create a trigger in which it creates a new user?

Tags: oracle, triggers

if it is possible... how can do that? i'm new in databases , please help me!
i'm using oracle and I want when create a new user when I insert a new row in a table "users"

Comment: You may get a better response if you post what you have tried and where you are having problems. To answer your question though: [yes you can](http://www.dbasupport.com/forums/showthread.php?52849-CREATE-USER-from-within-a-trigger-get-ORA-03001-unimplemented-feature)

Comment: This is not the right approach.  You should consider a stored procedure to create a user, which inserts a record into the table when it's completed.  Apart from anything else, a table+trigger means passwords stored in clear (as in the solution @JGreenwell links to) and that's a bad idea

Comment: @apc that (password in the clear) is mentioned in the comments in that link. Thanks for stating it more clearly

Answer (score 0):

As JGreenwell has mentioned, yes, you can do it, but is is not a good idea. The main problem is not the password in clear, is the transactional side effects.

Let's see the solution to password in clear:

It is easy to solve the problem of the password (do not store password in clear, encrypt it or hash it). If you have installed DMBS_CRYPTO and have privileges on it then you can create a procedure (I assume you have a table USERS with to columns: USERNAME and USERPASS):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MYCREATEUSER( NAME VARCHAR, PASS VARCHAR ) 
IS
  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE USER ' || NAME || ' IDENTIFIED BY "' || PASS || '"';
END;
```

and a trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TUSERS BEFORE INSERT ON USERS FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    MYCREATEUSER(:NEW.USERNAME, :NEW.USERPASS);
    :NEW.USERPASS := DBMS_CRYPTO.HASH(:NEW.USERPASS, DBMS_CRYPTO.HASH_SH1);
END;
```

Your insert statement uses the username and the password, the trigger creates the user, but before inserting the row it replaces the password with its SHA1 hash value. You must remember this when you query the table.

One example:

```
INSERT INTO USERS VALUES('Mary', 'Mary123');
```

To check:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM USERS 
  WHERE USERNAME = 'Mary' AND 
        USERPASS = DBMS_CRYPTO.HASH('Mary123', DBMS_CRYPTO.HASH_SH1);
```

If count = 1 then the user and password exists, but if count = 0 the user/password does not exists.

This example only works if: you have installed DBMS_CRYPTO and has enough privileges, and you have CREATE TABLE privileges (remember that when a procedure executes statements it only has explicit granted privileges, privileges that came from ROLES are disabled - so, it is not enough to have the RESOURCE privilege, you need the CREATE TABLE explicit privilege).

But as I have mentioned it is not a good idea, because you can be affected by transactional side effects. Let's see the main problem:

To maintain ACID principles (Atomicity, Consistency, Isolation and Durability) Oracle needs to ensure that one statement is viewed as an Atomic operation. If I execute INSERT INTO USERS SELECT * FROM OTHER_USER_TABLES this statement must be viewed as an atomic unit. The atomic unit starts when you send the statement and ends when oracle notifies you the error/ok code.

But trigger is executed inside the statement (inside its temporal scope). The trigger controls the insert statement (if it fails all the statement fails, if it says ok, the statement is ok). Note that the statement ends after the triggers finalization. This means that it is not possible to commit or rollback the current transaction before the statement ends (because in this case the Atomicity is not ensured). So, a trigger cannot COMMIT/ROLLBACK the current transaction (it cannot commit and it cannot call a procedure to commit it, nobody can do it before statement ends).
CREATE TABLE is an autocommit statement (if forces a commit) so it is not possible to CREATE a table inside the trigger scope.

But we say "you can" and we have a working example. How?
The answer is the PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION.
This pragma forces oracle to execute the affected PL/SQL block in a new different transaction. So, in our example, oracle executes MYCREATEUSER procedure in a new transaction.

Oracle does not have a nested transaction model, so the inner AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION does not depend on the outer trigger's transaction. They are both flat transactions. This means that if the procedures ends (the user is created) and the insert finally fails (due to any reason) the row is not in the table but the new user exists.

Let's see an example:

```
INSERT INTO USERS VALUES ('Anne', 'An232131');
INSERT INTO USERS VALUES ('Mike', "ABC123');
ROLLBACK;
```

This examples inserts two rows (it creates two users) and rollback the transaction. So, finally the inserts are canceled and the rows (Anne an Mike) are not in users table. But Anne and Mike Oracle's users exists (the rollback) does not affect the user creation because they have been created by a different transaction that finally commited (the autonomous transaction).

This problem is not easy to solve without a nested transactional model (in a nested transactional model a inner transaction only finally commits when its outer transaction does).